# How do I insert an inner class in a main activity class (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, inner-classes, static-classes

Im trying to insert a static class as an inner class with the objective of making use of a Dialog Fragment in android studio to display a calendar.

I have tried to insert the following code right after the end of the main class but seems like it is not the appropriate place for it.

```
Public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment 
implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
@Override
Public Dialog onCreateDialog (Bundle saved[enter image description here][1]InstanceState){
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

....

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDnqt.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CLjR.png)

Comment: `Public static class` this is not valid java. Please fix the casing. Also show your activity class. You don't need to show any of the methods and attributes in it, but you need to show enough for us to understand what you have tried. Then show the error you get.

Comment: I suggest putting your fragment class in its own file rather than futzing around with a static inner class.

Answer (score 1):

static classes must go within the main class (or any other class), I would personally recommend at the end, but its not required.